# Pandas: Attaching Descriptive Dict() to Hierarchical Index (i.e. CountryCode and CountryName)

Tags: python, pandas

Is there anyway to attach a descriptive version to an Index Column?

For Example, I use ISO3 CountryCode's to merge from different data sources
'AUS' -> Australia etc. This is very convenient for merging different data sources, but when I want to print the data I would like the description version (i.e. Australia). I am imagining a dictionary attached to the Index Column of 'CountryCode' (where CountryCode is Key and CountryName is Value) and a flag that will print the Value instead of the Key which is used for data manipulation.

Is the best solution to generate my own Dictionary() and then when it comes time to print or graph to then merge the country names in? This is ok, except it would be nice for ALL of the dataset information to be carried within the dataframe object.

Answer (score 1):

I think the simplest solution split this into two columns in your DataFrame, one for country_code and country_name (you could name them something else).

*When you print or graph you can select which column is used.*

Comment: Agree, except that I use stack() and unstack() a lot to reshape the data (i.e. to get balanced panels across years). I would prefer not to carry the redundant CountryName information around as a specified Index in these pivots but rather keep the Index to the minimum info for fast referencing. After all of the reshaping I could merge the country names back in as a separate column.

Comment: Or keep a dict/series with the column_codes to columns_names, then after reshaping, do `df['country_name'] = df.country_code.apply(d.get)` ?

Comment: Perhaps I should invest more time into the Panel() structure rather than three hierarchical elements :)

Answer (score 0):

The index option has a format method that lets you apply a formatter in the form of a function:

```
In [1]: df = DataFrame([1,2], index=['AUS','CAN']); df
Out[1]:
     0
AUS  1
CAN  2

In [2]: d = {'AUS':'Australia', 'CAN':'Canada'}

In [3]: df.index.format(formatter = lambda x: d.get(x, x))
Out[3]: ['Australia', 'Canada']
```

I'm not sure how you would use this practically, though.

Comment: This looks promising ... I will look into formatter more. But this solution will still require me to maintain a DataFrame and a Dict() of CountryCode to CountryName mappings, rather than carrying the information in a single DataFrame. Might be designed that way as it would be possible on subsequent merges/joins etc. to have valid keys but not necessarily valid keynames!

Comment: This works quite well to replace the Index Codes prior to printing etc ...

    df = DataFrame([1,2], index=['AUS', 'CAN']); df
    d = {'AUS': 'Australia', 'CAN':'Canda'}

Then use

    df.index = df.index.map(lambda x: d.get(x,x))

I will also look into the formatter! Thanks